# Unregister 'old pns handles' on app uninstallation/update

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, push-notification

I have a azure Notification Hub, which notification pushs are triggered from a backend (via REST).
On the client side, there is a Xamarin.Android app, which registers against the azure hub endpoint (configured with google FCM).

When the app registers to this hub, a PNS identifier + registrationId combination is built. Additional the Tags-property is used as a subscription-list.

The problem is:
When the app is uninstalled, the PNS identifier + registration ID + Tags-list is still in the azure notification hub registered. As a consequence, when the app is installed again I still get push notifications for the device with the 'old registration'.

How can I handle this? Hooking on an uninstall-app-event is not possible as far as I read.

Comment: "As a consequence, when the app is installed again I still get push notifications for the device with the 'old registration'.", usually PNS is generated with device id, what do you want to achieve when you reinstall your app? Any problem with notifications?

Comment: I want to achieve derigstration from the google FCM service when the app is getting uninstalled, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same problem like receiving old registration push notification after uninstall the app from mobile and reinstalling. Did you find any solution for this?